# How does one test an ember component in block form?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember-cli and am writing some tests for my components. Is there a way (in the test) to pass in some block content to the component so that I can test the component use in block form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what you are passing to the component, it is just a template that is being wrapped by your component. Your unit test will be testing **only** the component which will remain the same regardless of the template it renders.

If you are trying to test how the component behaves during user interaction, you are talking about integration/acceptance tests. In that case you don't need to pass a block to the component because you'll be visiting routes that render templates where you have already set up your blocks.